# HttpClient with chunk data not working

Tags: c#, uwp, dotnet-httpclient

When I execute the query in Firefox/IE I get the full response; but when I execute the same request with `HttpClient` I get only a part. I don't understand why.

Apparently the data are chunked that's why I specify the `ResponseContentRead`.

```
var requestUri = "https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/continents/1/floors/1";

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
request.RequestUri = requestUri;

var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Why Firefox/IE returns the right response and `HttpClient` an incomplete one ?

Result from `HttpClient`:

[image: bad result]

Result from Firefox/IE:

[image: good result]

The code is inside a C# UWP app.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully ran your code and gotten the entire json string. However, I had to make a minor modification in order to get it working:

```
var requestUri = new Uri("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/continents/1/floors/1");

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
request.RequestUri = requestUri;

var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Note the `requestUri` being initialized as an Uri instance instead of a string instance.

Also, the code has been tested in a console application.

EDIT: Here is a paste of what I got from the call. I've beautified the code to make it more readable. Perhaps it helps you validate if the content is as expected: [Json result](https://jsfiddle.net/815umzvf/)

Comment: The `requestUri` I used is already an `Uri`. You have the complete response. If is it workig for you I can assume that there is a problem in UWP/WinRT app ...

Comment: @Adrien I'm not familiar with UWP, but I'd assume the .NET implementation wouldn't differ in this manner.

Comment: I tested the code in a console app and it's not working. I don't have the complete result. Are you sure you copy the result from the code and not the browser ?

Comment: @Adrien Is your system set up to use a proxy server? I'm not sure if that mattered, but it might be worth looking into it.

Comment: @Adrien I've tested it in LINQPad. I'll fire up a visual studio project and let you know.

Comment: @Adrien I can confirm I get the same answer in a .NET 4.5 Console application, also.

Comment: Could you please add these checks to your code and compare if you have the same result size as myself. `var isChunked = response.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked;
            var pagination = response.Headers.Contains("X-Result-Total");

            Debug.Assert(isChunked == true && pagination, "not good");
            Debug.WriteLine($">>>>>>>>> size = {result.Length}");`

Comment: I have a size of ">>>>>>>>> size = 646162"

Comment: @Adrien I am getting >>>>>>>>> size = 646162 while both isChunked and pagination are true.

Comment: Okay I think I found the issue, If the automatic decompression is turned on I don't have the complete message. Turned off, If have no issue.

Comment: @Adrien If you found a working solution for your problem, post an answer describing the way you managed to fix it. It might help others in your situation (or even yourself, in the years to come).